# How can I use \dbox in a caption?

Tags: boxes, fancybox

I’m trying to use a `\dbox` from the `dashbox` package in the caption of a figure, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dashbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering Imagine some figure here

        \caption{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result I get looks like expected:[image: Dashbox in caption]
However, I get plenty of errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \caption{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
Undefined control sequence. \caption{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \caption{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
Extra \or. \caption{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
...
```

The package documentation says:

> `\dbox{text}` works like `\fbox`, but the box is drawn with dashed lines.

But `\fbox` works fine inside a caption.

The boxes from the `fancybox` package seem to have similar problems.

What is the correct way to draw a dashed box in a caption?

Comment: Use `\caption{\protect\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}`

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If an alternative text for the list of figures is provided, `\dbox` can be used without further ado

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dashbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering Imagine some figure here

        \caption[text for list of figures]{\dbox{Boxed text} in caption.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```